Module '"pdfjs-dist"' has no exported member 'PDFViewerParams'. error when trying to upgrade pdfjs-dist from version 2.5.207 to 4.6,x

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry' in 'module\src\lib\components\pdf\render'

Error: pdf-render.component.ts:5:41 - error TS2305: Module '"pdfjs-dist"' has no exported member 'PDFViewerParams'.
5 import {PDFDocumentProxy, PDFPageProxy, PDFViewerParams} from 'pdfjs-dist';
Getting errors when try to upgrade pdfjsdist package with Angular 18 , works fine in 2.5.207 version . but fails to upgrade to 4x
trying to upgrade pdfjs-dist from version 2.5.207 to 4.6.82  with Angular 18
